Normalization and ordinary double points
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two integral projective complex varieties and $f:X\to Y$ be a finite morphism. I assume that
(1) $X$ is smooth,
(2) $f$ is the normalization morphism of $Y$, and
(3) each fiber of $f$ is either a single point or two different points.
Question: Does $Y$ have at worst ordinary double point singularities? Is it true that $f$ is unramified in this case?
The example in my mind is when $Y$ is a nodal curve. This example satisfies all assumptions above such that $f$ is unramified. Thanks in advance.

What about a cuspidal curve?

This is very far from true in higher dimensions. In fact, ordinary double points of dimension $\ge 2$ are normal.

There exist non-normal double points for surfaces, arising from the projection by an external point containing a bi-secant line to a smooth surface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$  (the embedding dimension is $4$ and the tangent cone is given by two planes intersecting at a single point). So, the answer is negative in dimension $2$.
